# I need to take a 0-5V signal and scale it to a 0-1.5V signal. How can I do this?

Tags: power, signal, low-power, conversion

I need to take a 0-5V signal and scale it to a 0-1.5V signal. How can I do this? I've seen posts using op-amps, but I'm not sure how to approach this with my voltage ranges.

Comment: Can you provide more information on what the signal is coming from, and what you want to do with it? You might be able to do this with just two resistors.

Comment: A voltage divider is the way to go, if you don't care about output impedance being high.

Comment: The signal originates in a PWM from an Arduino. It is being converted to a 0-5V signal. Off of the PCB I need to scale the voltage down to 0-1.5V.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a voltage-divider circuit with bufferred output that'll divide your 0-5V input down to 0-1.5V output. Buffer amp is optional if you're ok with an output impedance of >=22K.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFG9GG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: @DavidMiron, you can use larger or smaller values for the potential divider resistors provided that the 7:3 ratio is maintained for correct voltage division. Make them high enough that the input current drawn is suitable for your input source. Don't make them so high that they form an RC filter with the op-amp input and PCB track capacitance and distort your input waveform with a low slew rate.